# XFS Volume has wrong blocksize after being mounted

Tags: linux, xfs

I did the following:

```
$ mkfs.xfs -b size=4096 /dev/xvdf
meta-data=/dev/xvdf              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=131072 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=524288, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0

$ blockdev --report /dev/xvdf
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512  4096          0      2147483648   /dev/xvdf
```

Then after mounting it, the BSZ (blocksize) reported is wrong. It's now 512 instead of 4096.

```
$ mount /dev/xvdf /mntmnt
$ blockdev --report /dev/xvdf
RO    RA   SSZ   BSZ   StartSec            Size   Device
rw   256   512   512          0      2147483648   /dev/xvdf
```

Is that an issue or is it just blockdev that's messing up?

Comment: Almost certainly not an issue. Try blockdev --getbsz /dev/xvdf (output should be 4096).

Comment: I'm getting 512... :(

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried unmounting /dev/xvdf and then running blockdev --setbsz 4096 /dev/xvdf?

Comment: when I unmounted I get the correct value, that's the weirdest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the `blockdev` command...

If I run the following, I get the correct output:

```
$ file -s /dev/xvdf
/dev/xvdf: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 256, v2 dirs)
```